# Is attribution necessary even if not distributed?

Tags: attribution, permissive

With permissive licenses requiring attributions (MIT, BSD, etc.), are attributions ONLY required if the OSS is distributed?

Comment: Just for clarity, neither of those licenses uses the term "attribution" at all. For BSD-3 clause license, it specifically says only "Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice" and then a following statement "Redistributions in binary form ...". So, at least that license says nothing about something which is not redistributed. Maybe you could clarify what your actual goal is here (if you're not going to distribute the software, what are you planning to do instead?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For all practical purposes, requirements imposed on you by an open-source license only come into effect when you (re-)distribute the (modified) work.

If you don't distribute your changes, then nobody but yourself could ever notice if you followed the license requirements or not.